# Why do exported variables but not aliases from .bash_profile work in non-login shells?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm using the Fedora 20 graphical desktop. I found the **alias** put in the .bash_profile didn't have effect. Then I find the graphical terminal is not a login shell, so the bash_profile is not read at all.

Now it's weird to me that the **export** command does have effect in .bash_profile.
My .bash_profile is as below:

```
#bash_profile    
export mytest=bash_profileIsRead
alias kk=ls
```

Test result:

```
$ shopt login_shell
login_shell off
$ echo $mytest
bash_profileIsRead
$ kk
bash: kk: command not found...
```

Comment: As a side note, you can list your aliases by just running "alias".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing unusual or surprising about this.

Your `.bash_profile` is run once per session, by your login shell. It is **not** run by other shells run later in your session.

`.bashrc`, by contrast, is run by every interactive shell instance, so things like aliases and shell functions placed there will be honored throughout the session.

Environment variables only need to be set once, because they're inherited by subprocesses (every subprocess, not just shells!). Aliases are not inherited, so they need to be set in every shell.

See [the DotFiles page on the wooledge.org wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles) (maintained by irc.freenode.org's #bash channel) for more.

Answer (score 3):

Aliases are not inherited like environment variables. They should not be placed in profile, but instead in the .bashrc file.

Basically, .profile (or .bash_profile) is for things that are inherited (e.g. env variables) and the rc file is for things that must be re-initialized in non-login shells, such as aliases.

Comment: Well -- aliases *are* inherited by subshells. They're just not inherited by regular subprocess, even when those regular subprocesses happen to be shells. A subshell, after all, is a shell created by a `fork()` with no following `exec()`.

Comment: Of course that is what I _meant_, but you're right in that my terminology wasn't correct.